# Get Icon Name Placed In `~/.icons`

Tags: icons, .desktop

If we go to `/usr/share/applications` the icon names are like

```
Icon=org.gnome.Screenshot
Icon=preferences-desktop-theme
```

Suppose, I have a icon in `~/.icons/search.png`

How can I use that icon as the application Icon. I know I can just use

```
Icon=~/.icons/search.png
```

But I am trying to use icon name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your icon placed in `~/.local/icons` or in `~/.icons`, it will be picked up by simply specifying the file name without extension, i.e. `search` in your case. "Modern" practice requires placing icons under `~/.local/icons`. The traditional location, `~/.icons`, still works. Valid graphics formats for icons are png, xpm and svg.